# Finding counter gaps with SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I find a great SQL in StackOverflow to find the gaps in the counter. For example, if it has 1 2 3 7 8 9, it can find that 4 5 6 are missing. The SQL is outstanding but I could not understand its basics. My table contains incoming packets (with a frame counter) from different devices. So there is a column for the counter and another one for the deviceId. How can I find the missing packets for each device with only one SQL?

This is the code that finds the gap:

```
SELECT
 CONCAT(z.expected, IF(z.got-1>z.expected, CONCAT(' thru ',z.got-1), '')) AS missing
FROM (
 SELECT
  @rownum:=@rownum+1 AS expected,
  IF(@rownum=YourCol, 0, @rownum:=YourCol) AS got
 FROM
  (SELECT @rownum:=0) AS a
  JOIN YourTable
  ORDER BY YourCol
 ) AS z
WHERE z.got!=0;
```

It produces something like this:

| missing |
| --- |
| 4 thru 6 |

But I am searching for like this:

| deviceID | missing |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 thru 6 |
| 2 | 3 thru 8 |

Comment: Is this to find missing values in an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column? Why do you need to know the missing values?

Comment: What is **precise** MySQL version?

Comment: *But I am searching for like this* Search by the term "gaps and islands".

Comment: It is not auto inc. This is the frame count of incoming packets and there can be missing packets. @BillKarwin

Comment: MySQL version is 8.0.28